# Deploying a Vue.JS application as a 'widget' into an existing website

Tags: vue.js

We have built a little search and list results application using Vue CLI / and REST on the backend.  It is working well and addresses a common need within our organization.  It seems like we should be able to take the 'packaged'/deployed version of it and give instructions to other websites within our organization to include it on their website.  Similar to how google maps and others have instructions to copy and paste a snippet of code into your web page.  Any suggestions on how to go about that for a Vue.js 3 application?

Comment: The question doesn't mention your setup. If it's Vue CLI, you need to disable chunks (code splitting) and hashes in webpack config. Then you make sure that there are no more than 1 .js and 1 .css files in /dist with constant names and just load them on a page and make sure there's an element with the same selector as in mount(). Then you write JS script for embedding that creates these `<script>`, etc tags on a page where the app is injected. Can't give a specific recipe for these steps. Hope this helps.

Comment: `iframe` or `Webpack module federation`, or ...